# Should a WCF SOAP Service required by an ASP.NET MVC Web Application be invoked client side or server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

In Visual Studio 2013 U4 Ultimate, I have a solution targeting .NET 4.5.3 with:

1. An ASP.NET 5.2 MVC Web Application project based public website
2. A WCF SOAP Service with some operations

Security is important as the service is dealing with financial transactions.

The WCF Service could either be invoked from JavaScript in the web browser or alternatively the web browser could send a request to the Web Application to invoke the WCF Service on the server side and return the result.

What are the factual advantages and disadvantages of invoking the service client side or server side?

How do I choose to invoke from client side or server side based on technological facts?

Is there a convention, vendor recommended practice, or known best practice for whether client side or server side invocation should be used?

Comment: possibly **primarily opinion-based**

Comment: This is not opinion based.  I am asking for direction on how I should choose, based on facts, and facts are not opinions.  In any case, I have updated the question to clearly state I want factual answers not subjective ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat subjective - however, the security shouldn't dictate server vs. client - you either have to secure the web site or secure the service.

If you can't guarantee security on the service itself, or someone understanding exactly how the service is called and used could open the door to possibility of abuse, then don't expose it to the client side. Anything that lives on the client is unsafe and can/will be manipulated at some point.

Either way, the end-user shouldn't notice a big difference with either approach if implemented properly.

Comment: I mentioned the security as an additional point, however the main thing is whether there is a convention recommended by vendors or otherwise used in the industry?

Comment: There is a general shift toward pages being lightweight with calls to services done on the client side...